# Writing a package: Best practices regarding dependencies

Tags: best-practices, package-writing, dependencies

Some dependencies may be obvious and necessary for the basic function of a package. But what about secondary features which would require loading additional external packages? To clarify: I understand that 'adding too many features' is a common beginner's mistake. I'm by no means an experienced developer, but I'm not considering completely arbitrary features either.

To give some examples:

- a new environment contains an (optional) field for a date. This can be set to "today", fixed to some user-defined date, or left out altogether. This would require the datetime-package.
- Similarly, a field for a list of abbreviations. This would require the glossaries-package, which seems to be a pretty big package to load if the user doesn't need it.
- I would like to provide a certain page-style with this package, but leave it to the user to decide whether they want to use it. This would require the fancyhdr package.
- and some more.

My questions then are:

- Am I worrying too much about optimisation and should just go ahead with dependencies for nice-to-have features?
- Can I load these packages conditionally, e.g. by placing "RequirePackage" only inside the dependent macro(s)? Or via a package-option?
- Can I add support for these packages in case the user decides to load it themselves? How would I best inform them about this?
- Should I just remove these nice-to-have features altogether?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not prepared to try to answer the actual question, but it seems important to be aware that, if a package will require specific options, and there isn't a clean way to set them after the package has already been loaded, that would definitely affect the ordering of package loading as well as requiring very good documentation.

Comment: You can make a package option "fancyhead" set a boolean `\fancyheadtrue` and then have the package loading and setup inside `\iffancyhead`. That way a feature is opt-in for the user. Especially with big packages like glossaries or fancyhdr (not big, but e.g. not nice with KOMA) that is a good option.